# Scrollwheel to scroll only child content and not body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a div with overflow auto that can be scrolled with in a scrollwheel. When it reaches the end it scrolls the main body. How do I get it to  just stop when it reaches the end and not scroll the main body?

I don't want to do anything hacky like temporarily put the main body at overflow none.

Comment: Give the elements that aren't in the scrollwheel fixed position. `position:fixed;`

Comment: Please post the relevant code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Preview:** http://jsfiddle.net/eXQf3/559/

Try this fiddle
seems to be working

```
$('#test').bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(e) {
    var scrollTo = null;

    if (e.type == 'mousewheel') {
        scrollTo = (e.originalEvent.wheelDelta * -1);
    }
    else if (e.type == 'DOMMouseScroll') {
        scrollTo = 40 * e.originalEvent.detail;
    }

    if (scrollTo) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).scrollTop(scrollTo + $(this).scrollTop());
    }
});
```